# How to work with cookies in Struts 2

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, cookies, struts2

I am using cookie to avoid havind SID (session id). I try to set the cookie using the following method and retrieve it in my jsp file as shown blew, but it does not work. it just shows HelloSESSIONID.

Java

```
public class Users {

 public void setcookie(){
      Cookie user = new Cookie("User","Miro");
      user.setMaxAge(60*60);
 }
```

Jsp

```
<%@ page language="java"%>
<% Cookie cookies[] = request.getCookies(); 

           for (int i=0; i<cookies.length; i++) 
       {

        out.println("Hello"+cookies[i].getName()+ "> ");
       }
            %>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using cookies with Struts 2 and Struts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350554/using-cookies-with-struts-2-and-struts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a path for your cookies. 
For example to make it accessible in all pages of your application use the following

```
 user.setPath("/");
 or
 user.setDomain("example.com");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Cookie user = new Cookie("User","Miro");
user.setMaxAge(60*60);
```

You have to send the cookie, too:

```
response.addCookie(user);
```

Comment: But you do know that the user can see and update the contents of his cookies at will? Fine for screen names, not so good for security-relevant things.

Comment: I have two questions first is how to create that response object ? do you know of any alternative for security-relevant cases?

Comment: You don't "create" the response object, the servlet container gives it to you. The usual alternative for security-relevant data is server-side session storage (which you don't seem to like for some reason).

Comment: @MirMoorido there's a `HttpServletResponse response` parameter in your `doGet` and your `doPost` methods of your servlet.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I am using strust2 and need to implement these in action class would yhou give me an example for that?

Comment: @MirMoorido then use the proper tags for your question and provide the real code you're working with, we can't just guess your exact problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example to use cookies with Struts 2.

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport implements ServletResponseAware, ServletRequestAware {

      public int division;

      public String execute() {

        // Load from cookie
        for(Cookie c : servletRequest.getCookies()) {
          if (c.getName().equals("cookieDivision"))
            division=Integer.parseInt(c.getValue());
        }

        // Save to cookie
        Cookie div = new Cookie("cookieDivision", String.format("%d",division));
        div.setMaxAge(60*60*24*365); // Make the cookie last a year
        servletResponse.addCookie(div);

        return "success";
      }

      // For access to the raw servlet request / response, eg for cookies
      protected HttpServletResponse servletResponse;
      @Override
      public void setServletResponse(HttpServletResponse servletResponse) {
        this.servletResponse = servletResponse;
      }

      protected HttpServletRequest servletRequest;
      @Override
      public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
        this.servletRequest = servletRequest;
      }
    }
```